# Problema button clic function jquery con datatables bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla más o menos así. En el botón eliminar tengo una clase que utilizo para eliminar el registro desde ajax. el código de la tabla de manera simplificada es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Publicado</th>
            <th>Vencimiento</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Visitas Únicas</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <tr>1</tr>
            <tr>Título1</tr>
            <tr>2018-08-20</tr>
            <tr>2018-09-20</tr>
            <tr>Activa</tr>
            <tr>6</tr>
            <td><a href="htt://sitioweb.com/a"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar"  id="785">Eliminar</button> </td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <tr>2</tr>
            <tr>Título2</tr>
            <tr>2018-08-22</tr>
            <tr>2018-09-23</tr>
            <tr>Activa</tr>
            <tr>5</tr>
            <td><a href="htt://sitioweb.com/a"><button class="btn btn-info">Editar</button></a></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger eliminar"  id="786">Eliminar</button> </td>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Todo funciona de maravilla (aparentemente), el inconveniente es que el botón "eliminar" solo me funciona para la primera página, a partir de la página 2, al dar clic a los botones no se desencadena mi código jquery :( lo peor es que desde la consola no me manda ningún error, simplemente no responde, además de que ya revisé el código y el plugin no está agregando ningún código adicional >.<

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La url del plugin que estoy usando es: https://datatables.net/manual/index

Comment: Deberias de agregar el codigo donde declaras el dataTable y el handler del boton Eliminar.

Comment: Solo estoy declarando la tabla así: $('#mytable').dataTable();

Comment: Entonces como generas las columnas de `#mytable`

Comment: Lo hace el plugín de manera automática, mira: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: No entiendo. Que quieres hacer ?

Comment: Entonces incluye el handler del boton eliminar?

Comment: Listo gracias, ya lo he resuelto, ya publiqué la respuesta :) muy amable!

Comment: como sabes que registro eliminar? necesitamos saber el código que elimina para saber si estas identificando de manera correcta al elemento que quieres eliminar, porque si estas usando algo así como el número de fila pues déjame decirte que esa librería "rehace" la tabla cada vez que cambias de página por lo que si muestras 10 registros por página estos tendrán siempre índices del 0 al 9 (o del 1 al 10)

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen, lo importante de contar con la versión inglesa de stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858738/datatables-jquery-click-event-not-working-after-pagination

```
$("#tableId").on("click", ".activeAccount", function(){
   // your code goes here
});
```